# What is the proper way to identify screen, plasmoid is running on?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, kde-plasma, kde4

Currently I'm developing KDE Plasma/Wallpaper plugin with D-Bus interface(small learning project). I have multi-monitor setup and would like to be able to address each D-Bus Plasma/Wallpaper instance independently(running on different monitors or even on separate KDE Activities) and my initial idea was simple: register separate D-Bus services with unique name(i.e. "com.example.prettydesktop.wlp-"+unique_screen_id) for each instance of plugin. However I couldn't find any way to get screen id from PyKDE **Wallpaper** because it's not **QWidget** subclass and thus I can't use **QDesktopWidget.screenNumber** method.

```
class DbusWlp(Wallpaper):
    def __init__(self, parent, args=None):
        Wallpaper.__init__(self, parent)

    # Plasmoid init code should go here
    def init(self, config):
        # also tried QX11Info but I think it's not relevant here
        print QtGui.QX11Info().appScreen() # always returns 0
        print QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(self) # doesn't work because self is not QWidget subclass
        print QtGui.QApplication.desktop().isVirtualDesktop() # returns True just in case
```

The main question is: **What is the proper way to identify what screen plasma plugin(wallpaper or plasmoid) is running on?** And a small additional question: Is there any better way to implement cross-widget communication then D-Bus?
I'm fairly new both to PyQT and PyKDE so I could easily missed something obvious and ANY help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

PS: Sorry for my poor English - it's not my mother tongue.